# How can I fix my code that shows me segmentation fault on C?

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault

For my assignment, I am trying to recreate the turtle graphics in C. Basically when you enter a series of commands, my program processes the commands and draws a shape in a 50 by 50 array(floor) accordingly. When I run my program, it keeps on giving me segmentation fault error and I don't know what that means so I can't spot out my mistake.

This is my code:

```
int facing = 3; //start by facing east
int pen = 1; //start by pen up
int copyToArrays(int commandCheck[2][2], const int commands);
int readCommand(int commandCheck[]);
void performCommand(const int command, const int factor, int floor[50][50]);
void draw(const int floor[50][50]);
// y and x coordinates of turtle
int posX =0;
int posY =0;

int main(void)
{
    //INSTRUCTIONS
    printf("Command Key: \n\n");
    printf("1 ---- pen up\n");
    printf("2 ---- pen down\n");
    printf("3 ---- turn right\n");
    printf("4 ---- turn left\n");
    printf("5, N ---- move forward N spaces\n");
    printf("6 ---- Print 50 by 50 Floor\n");
    printf("9 ---- End Data\n\n");
   
    printf("Enter your commands.\n");
    int floor[50][50] = {{0}, {0}};// floor of length and width of 50
    int commandArrays[100][2] = {{0}, {0}};// arrays for the commands
    int numberOfCommands = 0;
    
    numberOfCommands = copyToArrays(commandArrays, 100);// calculate how many commands to process
    
    //for loop to go through the commands and perform them one by one
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numberOfCommands; i++)
    {
        performCommand(commandArrays[i][0], commandArrays[i][1], floor);
    }
}


// function to copy commands into arrays and return the number of commands 
int copyToArrays(int commandArray[2][2], const int commands)
{
    int i;
    int arr[2];
    for ( i  = 0; i <commands && readCommand(arr); i++)
    {
        commandArray[i][0] = arr[0];
        commandArray[i][1] = arr[1];
    }
    
    return i;
}

// Function to take input commands from user
int readCommand(int commandCheck[])
{
    scanf("%d,%d", &commandCheck[0], &commandCheck[1]);
    
    if(commandCheck[0] != 5)
    {
        commandCheck[1] = 0;
    }
    
    if(commandCheck[0] == 9)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


// follow command and perform task accordingly
void performCommand(const int command, const int factor, int floor[50][50])
{
    int j; 
    switch(command)
    {
        case 1: pen = 1;
            break;
        case 2: pen = 0;
            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
            break;
        case 3: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    facing = 6;
                   }
               else if (facing == 6)
               {
                facing  = 9;
               } 
               else if (facing == 9)
               {
                facing = 12;
               }
               else
               {
                facing  = 3;
               }
               break;
          case 4: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    facing = 12;
                   }
               else if (facing == 12)
               {
                facing  = 9;
               } 
               else if (facing == 9)
               {
                facing = 6;
               }
               else
               {
                facing  = 3;
               }
               break;
           
           case 5: if (facing == 3)
                   {
                    for (j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posX++;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    
                   }
                   else if (facing == 6)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posY--;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   else if (facing == 9)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posX--;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   else if(facing == 12)
                   {
                    for(j = 1; j <= factor; j++)
                    {
                        posY++;
                        if(pen == 0)
                        {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                   }
                   break;
            case 6: draw(floor);
                    break;
            default:
            break;
    }
}


//FUntion to draw on the floor
void draw(const int floor[50][50])
{
    
     printf("\n");
     for (size_t i = 0; i <=49; i++)
     {
        for(size_t j = 49; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if(floor[i][j] == 1)
            {
                printf("%s", "*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        puts("");
     }
}
```

Comment: I should add that my assignment requires me to perform this without using pointers.

Comment: Add that in the question by doing an edit

Comment: @4386427 I was told that edits are only for improving code after feedback is given.

Comment: No, please don't improve the code you posted, or people won't follow the question that you asked. Unless you didn't copy enough of the code. This isn't an "interactive" debugging forum.

Comment: Wall of text!  Reduce your code, run it through a debugger and find where the problem is.  Have you made any effort to pinpoint where the problem is?

Comment: @Beakal Then someone told you something wrong.

Comment: @Beakal You should also edit your question and tell which input leads to the seg fault

Comment: No. Edits are for adding information to your question, whether it's because someone asked you to do so or just that you remember you should have said something. The only time you should use comments is when someone asks you something, and if that something is for more information, that needs to get edited into the question instead of a  comment.

Comment: With regard to your question, what does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you ?

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, the absolute best thing to do (in terms of a learning opportunity) is to get a core dump and learn how to use that core dump to tell you exactly where the segfault happens.

Comment: We need to know your input.... Anyway, the global variable `posX` can lead to seg fault because commands can be given so that it's incremented again and again and in the end you'll access the array out-of-bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for(size_t j = 49; j >= 0; j--)
```

When j == 0, the loop is entered.  When j is decremented, it does not become -1, since size_t is an unsigned type.  Turn up your compiler warnings.  When I compile your code, the compiler tells me:

```
a.c:181:30: warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '>= 0' is always true [-Wtype-limits]
  181 |         for(size_t j = 49; j >= 0; j--)
```

If your compiler doesn't tell you that, learn how to get that diagnostic.  (eg, with gcc, always compile with -Wall -Wextra and pay attention to what it tells you.)

Comment: For this reason it is often better to always write up-counting loops: `for(size_t j=0; j<50; j++) { something [50-1-j] = ... ; }`